# Float-left breaks at certain window width

Tags: html, css, css-float

Having a bug of a time figuring out where this is going wrong.

I have a section of HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <section style="float: left; width: 245px; height: 90%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <div>
            <br />
            <img src="/images/" />
            <font style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Operations</font>
            <ul>
                <li style="padding-top: 5px;"><a href="/">Home</a>
            </ul>
            <ul><li style="padding-top: 5px;"><a href="/viewsop/op">SOP</a><li style="padding-top: 5px;"><a href="/viewssop/op">SSOP</a></ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section style="margin-left: 250px; height: 100%; margin-right: 20px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;" id="pagewindow">
        <br />
        <center>
            <span class="pagetitle" id="pagetitle">
                Operations
            </span>
            <hr />
        </center>
            <div class="pagebody" id="pagebody">
                Operations Main Page
            </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Correct Look:

[image: Correct Look]

But when I hit a certain width, it jumps to this:

[image: Bad layout]

I have checked all the @media statements, none have a break point where this is happening.

My content css:

```
#content {
  padding: 0px 5px 20px 5px;
  height: 775px;
  max-width: 1335px;
}
```

I am at a loss of where else to look. Suggestions?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue via jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue.  It wasn't even in the area I thought.  I just started deleting code segments until the error disappeared then started adding it back in.

I have a `header div` that was `29px` tall, and I recently added an `image` as a link to 'Home'.  Turns out that image was `35px` tall, so ended up flowing over the `header div` and screwed up the `div` below it, the one I thought was broke.

Just goes to show, in HTML and CSS layout, look EVERYWHERE if you have an error